# Use of Edit.SelectToLastGoBack in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

There is a command in Visual Studio 2005 called Edit.SelectToLastGoBack (bound to Ctrl + =).

I presume it is supposed to select all the text between the current cursor position and the last 'Go Back' point, but I can't work out the algorithm it's using for deciding what that point is.

Does anyone know how to use this potentially very useful command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selects to the last juimp point ...

Try using the navigation bar to jump to another method in class. Then press Ctrl + "="

It will select from the start of method you jumped to all the way back to where you jumped from.

I have yet to find a use for it though TBH,

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Ah, jump points! I see. And you can also set a jump point using the Find command, or Page Up/Page Down. Now I just need to remember to try using this command.

Answer (score 1):

I use it for recording macros.

Frequently I want to select everything from this brace to that brace and cut it in a macro.  Go to the first brace, hit ctrl-f (ctrl-i doesn't work right in macros), search to the second brace, close search with escape, and hit ctrl-= to get everything between the braces selected.  This is much more reliably repeatable in a macro than something like using ctrl arrows to navigate a word at a time while holding down shift, and is similar to the emacs concept of setting a mark point.

I'm not sure what all starts a new 'location in navigation history', but I'm sure starting a search does and that's all I need.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this command is available in Visual Studio 2012. I've been looking for it ever since I got VS 2012. I kept thinking it was something like anchor, like select everything between the anchor and point. I was disappointed that macro recording and playing are no longer available. But I am glad this command still exists.

Another useful command is ctrl+k ctrl+a, which is Edit.SwapAnchor. So, you could be someplace in the code, then do a find. Now you have the point and anchor (maybe also known as the cursor and last goback). You can do ctrl+= to select, then ctrl+k ctrl+a then extend from the other end using another find--or something like that.